# Inheritance and the JSON formatter of ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api

Imagine a simple controller action `IEnumerable<BaseType> Get()`. It returns an enumeration of different types all deriving from BaseType.

When the client requests XML, the result is something like this:

```
<ArrayOfBaseType>
    <BaseType i:type="DerivedType1"><A>value</A></BaseType>
    <BaseType i:type="DerivedType2"><B>value</B></BaseType>
    <BaseType i:type="DerivedType3"><C>value</C></BaseType>
</ArrayOfBaseType>
```

As you can see, the type of the derived class is transmitted in the `i:type` attribute.

If the client requests JSON however, this information is missing:

```
[
  {"A":"value"},
  {"B":"value"},
  {"C":"value"}
]
```

How to fix this?

Comment: @downvoter: Without an explanation, your downvote is worth nothing as I can't improve the question without knowing what is unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following change is necessary:

In the WebApiConfig.cs the following line needs to be added:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = 
    TypeNameHandling.Auto;
```

This will automatically result in a new property `$type` when needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you write your class following:

```
public class MyClass
{
    // properties here

    public string IType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetType().Name;
        }

        set {  }
    }
}
```

Maybe, it will help you

Comment: Not really. In my eyes that's a hack.

Comment: I'm not sure with json exists another way.